# Unable to run Scheduler in server for every one hour

Tags: java

I have two node running in server. I have requrement like i need to run a method 3 times one is at 6:00 pm and 7:00 pm and 8:00 pm.

```
@Transactional("userTransactionManager")
public void userTxnConsolidatedMail() {
}

@Scheduled(cron = "0 00 18 * * *")
@SchedulerLock(name = "txnConsolidatedMailSchedulerOne", lockAtMostForString = "PT15M")
public void txnConsolidatedMailSchedulerOne() {
    userTxnConsolidatedMail();
}

@Scheduled(cron = "0 00 19 * * *")
@SchedulerLock(name = "txnConsolidatedMailSchedulerTwo", lockAtMostForString = "PT15M")
public void txnConsolidatedMailSchedulerTwo() {
    userTxnConsolidatedMail();
}

@Scheduled(cron = "0 00 20 * * *")
@SchedulerLock(name = "txnConsolidatedMailSchedulerThree", lockAtMostForString = "PT15M")
public void txnConsolidatedMailSchedulerThree() {
    userTxnConsolidatedMail();
}
```

Comment: I have used this cron expression also 0 0 18-20  * * * this also not working then i went for that approach.  calling 3 times same method with different cron expressions

Comment: What does "unable to run" mean? Is there an exception? Is the method not called?

Comment: no exceptions . It is working in my local . But same scheduler is not working in server.

Comment: On your server: Does it run at all but at the wrong time? Does it never run? Can you provide more detail on what is or is not happening?

Comment: Also can you confirm that your local has different data source that the servers' (you mentioned 2 nodes)? Maybe some other local is 'stealing' the job execution

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding comments to clarify. Comments may or may not be shown initially. Make it easy to help you by putting everything in one place. Clarify what "not working" and "unable to run" means. What happens? Can you log something in your code to show that it gets called? Anything in the server logs?